# Actualizar state array en React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Quiero actualizar en mi **state** *array* el valor de **cantidad** a +1 que contenga un  **key** especifico

```
    this.state = {
     producto:[
        0:{precio: 62, producto: "Cafe", key: "5cef2", cantidad: 1},
        1:{precio: 20, producto: "Soda", key: "2fbv", cantidad: 1}
        2:{precio: 50, producto: "Pastel", key: "1tej2", cantidad: 1}
     ]}
```

He encontrado este ejemplo pero no me funciona
alguien que me pueda ayudar que hice mal ..

```
masUnElemento(data){
        this.setState(state => {
            const agrega = this.state.producto.filter((item) => {
             if(item.key == data.key){
                item.cantidad == data.cantidad 
            })

            return {agrega}
        });
}
```

Comment: Primero tendrías que mostrar esos ejemplos que no te han funcionado para ver que ocurre, por el resto solo tienes que recorrer el producto y encontrar la key

Comment: agregue el ejemplo @Idanny7 sabes como puedo actualizar esos valores

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes lograr lo que deseas revisando que llave coincide con el producto al que quieres aumentar, aumentas su cantidad y luego actualizas el estado con un nuevo arreglo de productos de esta manera:

```
update(key) {
  const { productos: oldProductos } = this.state;
  // Iteramos sobre el arreglo y regresamos uno nuevo para actualizar el estado
  const productos = oldProductos.map(p => {
    // Revisamos que la llave recibida coincida con el elemento que queremos actualizar
    if (p.key === key) {
      // Actualizamos la cantidad
      p.cantidad += 1;
      // Regresamos el nuevo elemento con la cantidad actualizada
      return p;
    }
    // Si no es el elemento que deseamos actualizar lo regresamos tal como está
    return p;
  });

  this.setState(productos);
}
```

Aquí dejo un ejemplo funcional:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      productos: [
        {
          precio: 62,
          producto: "Cafe",
          key: "5cef2",
          cantidad: 1
        },
        {
          precio: 20,
          producto: "Soda",
          key: "2fbv",
          cantidad: 1
        },
        {
          precio: 50,
          producto: "Pastel",
          key: "1tej2",
          cantidad: 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }

  update(key) {
    const { productos: oldProductos } = this.state;
    const productos = oldProductos.map(p => {
      if (p.key === key) {
        p.cantidad += 1;
        return p;
      }
      return p;
    });

    this.setState(productos);
  }

  render() {
    const { productos } = this.state;
    return (
      <table>
        <thead>
          <th>Precio</th>
          <th>Producto</th>
          <th>Llave</th>
          <th>Cantidad</th>
          <th>&nbsp;</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {productos.map(p => (
            <tr key={p.key}>
              <td>{p.precio}</td>
              <td>{p.producto}</td>
              <td>{p.key}</td>
              <td>{p.cantidad}</td>
              <td>
                <button 
                  type="button" 
                  onClick={() => this.update(p.key)}
                >
                  +
                </button>
              </td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo normalmente extraigo el objeto del estado primero, lo trabajo y al final actualizo el estado:

```
masUnElemento(data) {
  let indexProducto = this.state.producto.findIndex(x => x.key === data.key);
  let producto = this.state.producto;
  producto[indexProducto].cantidad += data.cantidad;

  this.setState({ producto });
}
```

Comment: Gracias por el dato, me funciono,@kroneaux Schneider